# how do i specify the element when loading content ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

How can I specify an element where the content is to be retrieved from within the pageurl in the code below?

```
  $(function () {
     $("a[rel='sort']").click(function (e) {
         //e.preventDefault(); 
         /*  
    if uncomment the above line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
    if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link. 
    */

         //get the link location that was clicked
         pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

         //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
         $.ajax({
             url: pageurl + '?rel=sort',
             success: function (data) {
                 $('#content1').html(data);
             }
         });

         //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
         if (pageurl != window.location) {
             window.history.pushState({
                 path: pageurl
             }, '', pageurl);
         }
         return false;
     });
 });
```

Comment: what are you retrieving here, success: function (data) . Is it a a json array of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to get the response in a variable and then find your desired content

Try this

```
$.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=sort',success: function(data){
    var content = $(data).find("#IDofYouContent");
    $('#content1').html(content);
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery.load()] event

Details: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$(function(){
    $("a[rel='sort']").click(function(e){
     pageurl = $(this).attr('href')+"?rel=sort #elementToBeLoadedIn";
    $('#content1').load(pageurl);
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: can i still use $("a[rel='sort']").click(function(e){ to specify the url

Comment: i just did :) my rep wasn't high enough earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `load()` function, like so:

```
$('#content1').load(pageurl + '?rel=sort #elementToBeLoadedIn');
```

Check out the docs for more info: http://api.jquery.com/load/